What are the best books about human rating and feedback systems?
I'm studying evaluation data collection and rating evaluation of LLM models using platforms of human raters like Surge or Scale AI. I'm also studying how we can use survey methods of users of LLMs to learn more about them.
What are the best books on the statistics of ratings and evaluations of items, where one or multiple raters give feedback? This seems like in some ways to overlap with survey methods though it is different. This is distinct from RLHF or reward model learning.
I have seen other "what are the best books" questions on this site.
